# initial file from s3 not displaying react-dropzone

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, dropzone, react-dropzone

I'm using react-dropzone + s3 to upload images for a product and it's working fine.
The issue starts when I want to edit the product. I'm trying to display the images of the product in the react-dropzone component with the initialFiles prop, but they are not displaying correctly.

This is how the component looks:

```
  <DropzoneArea
   filesLimit={5}
   initialFiles={['https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myphoto.jpg']}
   maxFileSize={5000 * 5000}
   acceptedFiles={["image/*"]}
   onChange={(e) => setFiles(e)}
  ></DropzoneArea>
```

And this is what it shows

[image]

My guess is that the files are the complete link that is stored in the s3 bucket, and this is not an image as the dropzone would recognize it, but I don't know how to fix it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it following this:

https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/examples#!/Initial%20File%20From%20Data%20URL

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).